# Need to click, hold and move at certain coordinates with capybara(ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, headless, webautomation

Im trying to implement a click, drag and release at certain coordinates for a web page, headlessly using Capybara. The target is an element containing calendar, which responds to mouse events via ajax. Schedules are added via clicking, dragging and releasing. I have tried 2 methods:

**Method 1**

```
cal = find(:xpath, "//div[@class='dhx_cal_container']")
page.driver.browser.mouse.move_to(cal.native, 240, 250)
page.driver.browser.mouse.down
page.driver.browser.mouse.move_by(0, 150)
page.driver.browser.mouse.up
```

**Problem with method 1:** nothing is happening according to screenshots.

**Method 2**

```
driver.browser.action.move_to(native).move_by(x1, y1).click_and_hold.perform
driver.browser.action.move_to(native).move_by(x2, y2).release.perform
```

**Problem  with method 2:** click_and_hold always targets the center of the element.

Any ideas how to implement the click and drag in this case?

Answer (score 4):

You should use capybara's `drag_to` method

```
source = page.find('#foo')
target = page.find('#bar')
source.drag_to(target)
```

More info: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement%3Adrag_to

Comment: The thing is, dragging an element doesnt work. Its necessary to click the calendar element at certain point, and move the mouse up or down a few pixels.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered the Capybara cross driver drag_to drags the middle of one element onto the middle of another.  Since this doesn't meet your needs you do have to go driver specific -- in your case you've indicated selenium.  #click_and_hold should only click on the middle of an element if you pass it an element, which you're not.  Taking your Method 1 actions and translating into Method 2 style the following should do what you want

```
cal = find(:xpath, "//div[@class='dhx_cal_container']")
page.driver.browser.action.move_to(cal.native, 240, 250).
                           click_and_hold.
                           move_to(cal.native, 240, 400).
                           release.
                           perform
```

The offsets passed to move_to are from the top left corner of the cal.native element.  It does seem weird that the UIs behavior is just to drag the container around and drop it some offset away that isn't based on the position of any other element though.  Are you sure you really want to be selecting locations based on the container, and not dragging elements inside the container around?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. As you can see in original questions method 2, click_and_hold also targets the center of the element.

Comment: And yes it is needed to drag the mouse inside the element, moving elements inside the container is not the case.

Comment: @MiikaPalokangas  From selenium - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ab1e647d0fc8fc39e6b00ae94321ab228b6728f2/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb#L164  -  click_and_hold is only supposed to move to the middle of an element if one is passed ( it calls Mouse#down https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ab1e647d0fc8fc39e6b00ae94321ab228b6728f2/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb#L49 and only moves if element passed)-- without a passed element it should just do a mouse down.  If thats not the case for you, you might want to report it to the selenium project.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you're needing something that allows for greater control than just moving the the middle of an element. Would Selenium's `draganddropby` action do the trick? It allows you to set x,y offset coordinates.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/mouse_and_keyboard_actions_in_detail/#draganddropby